# Invalid Argument javascript error only on certain computers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Getting an error whenever we click a particular button/link on our site.  It is generating a javascript "Invalid Argument" error.  I know in the other posts it is typically because it is a syntax error in the javascript however it only just seems to have started happening and it doesn't happen on all pcs.

ie. in our client's environment if I remote onto their web server and view the uat website I get the javascript error.  If I remote onto their sql server and view the uat website I don't get the javascript error.  If it was a syntax error then I would always get the error wouldn't I?

both browsers are the same version of IE6 (yeah I know...) :)  I have tried deleting temporary internet files - including viewing the files and deleting them myself - but no joy.

client uses citrix.. and they're all getting the error :(

Any ideas would be appreciated - Thanks! :)

**Update** - Sorry I haven't posted specific code as there is too much to post (and I'm not sure where the error is occurring).  The "button" launches a new window which in turn opens up a couple of aspx pages and calls lots of javascript.  So the window opens ok, and there's a function that gets called to resize the window - but before it calls the resizing of the window/content it throws the invalid argument error.  Am busy trying to get alerts to trigger to see if I can see where it's falling over but so far no luck.

Again not sure why this error doesn't occur when I use a particular PC (same browser version)

Comment: Please show the line of code the error appears in

Comment: You left out the most important information. What code is being called when the button is clicked?

Comment: One thing to look for is code (in the "click" event handler, or called by that) which changes style attributes. IE is picky about what values can be assigned to what attributes.

Comment: Part of the problem is this is an application built by someone else - so it's taking awhile to even find what is being called.  Have tried adding alerts to see where it is falling over.  I still don't understand why it would happen on one PC and not another.. if they're both using the same version of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what this was - and I have since changed companies it can't be further investigated.  Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code for attaching your event listener to the button as well as the event listener?  This would be helpful in advising you on the best way to debug the error -- it's likely something to do with event object or the way you are referencing it.

Comment: Unfortunately quite a few files get loaded and so I'm not quite sure what code to post that would be of use (there is stacks of javascript being called as well as multiple aspx pages that get loaded in a popup).  I've tried catching errors and doing alerts to see if I could figure out which method its failing on but still can't track down where it's failing.

Comment: Hi Jen,  is this a publicly visible page?  I may be able to help if so.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - no its an intranet system.  Have since changed companies.  Thanks for the offer though! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without your code being posted, but most of the "Invalid Argument" IE issues I've encountered relate to setting a property or style on a DOM element that isn't supported by the IE6 DOM.

The error may be present on both browsers, but maybe script debugging is disabled on one and not the other, or they may have other JavaScript setting differences.  The browser that's working may just be silently stopping its script once the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing [Internet Explorer developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535). Using this tool, you can more easily pinpoint the exact problem. Just telling us "something doesn't work" won't help you or us.